# Neural Network output recognition

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, text-classification

In my environment, I have an LSTM network that has been trained to perform text generation using an input pattern string and a given dataset of words. Now I am facing a problem: it would be possible to perform a kind of recognition of a generated text, having as input the generated text, the train dataset and all the informations about the LSTM network (weights, layers, etc...)?
My idea is to use a second LSTM network able to classify the outputs of the first network, but it seems so redundant and not optimized. Another approach could be to try to invert the LSTM network, but it seems so difficult and not always possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code with the networks.

Comment: The code is similar to this one: https://towardsdatascience.com/text-generation-with-bi-lstm-in-pytorch-5fda6e7cc22c